# How to get last inserted row value in PHP and add 1 to it

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an iOS app to give users more options when they purchase a license. I'm mostly familiar with ObjC and xCode so I don't know much PHP.

Here is the setup of the MySql table:

[image: MySql table]

I'm trying to get the rw_app_id from the last entry in the table & +1 to it. Then enter it into a new row of the database. Below is the code I have constructed so far. Much help appreciated, I've entered over 2,500 entrees to this database manually and I'm so tired of doing it. Please help me keep my sanity. An explanation of code given would be great. Thanks.

```
$increase = stripslashes($_GET['increase']);
$email = stripslashes($_GET['email']);
$unlock = stripslashes($_GET['unlock']);
$numOf = stripslashes($_GET['numOf']);



$d = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
if (!$d) {
    header($header.': Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    exit();
}


mysql_select_db($db);
```

// THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK!

```
$rw_app_id = LAST_ROW(?)+1;
```

//

```
$q = "INSERT INTO rw_promo_code (id, rw_app_id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining) VALUES ('$increase', '$rw_app_id', '$email', '$unlock', '$numOf')";



$result = mysql_query($q);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}else{

echo "Entered Successfully";

}
```

Comment: why you need this? because Mysql will do that automatically when inserting

Comment: just change your id column to auto-increment and don't insert it. Edit: it is already auto increment!

Comment: @bansi: in the image the id is already incrementation

Comment: SELECT MAX(id) FROM rw_promo_code

Comment: I can't add the option Auto-Increment on rw_app_id: Incorrect table definition; there can only be one auto colum and it must be defined as a key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the line

```
$q = "INSERT INTO rw_promo_code (id, rw_app_id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining) VALUES ('$increase', '$rw_app_id', '$email', '$unlock', '$numOf')";
```

to

```
$q = "INSERT INTO rw_promo_code (rw_app_id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining) VALUES ('$rw_app_id', '$email', '$unlock', '$numOf')";
```

You won't need to calculate the last id and add 1 to it and then insert. MySQL will do that for you.

**Note:** Manual increment is dangerous as some other person may have inserted a row in between you calculate you next id and do the insert

For inserting `max+1 of rw_app_id` Try this code

```
$q = "INSERT INTO rw_promo_code (rw_app_id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining) SELECT (MAX(rw_app_id)+1), '$email', '$unlock', '$numOf' FROM rw_promo_code";
```

Comment: All you did was remove the id? That is already auto-incremented. I need rw_app_id incremented.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, (the max+1) but it seems I was misunderstanding the table and my iOS app. I actually need id incremented. Could you show me in a comment the same method but for incrementing id. Sorry for the trouble. I'll accept after I try.

Comment: the last code i posted increments both `id` and `rw_app_id`. the `id` increment is handled automatically by MySQL as it is declared as auto-increment. In the query `(MAX(rw_app_id)+1)` increments the `rw_app_id` column. Note: I have used `SELECT` to insert data.

Comment: Ok, now I understand why you removed id. Without it, it increments itself.  I had been updating this number for months one by one. :( This has definitely helped me understand select. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the last of *all the rows* in the table, then this is finally the time where `MAX(id)` is the right answer! :) kind of.

```
SELECT fields FROM rw_promo_codeORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
$q = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM rw_promo_code  "
```

fetches the last row id, then increment by 1

```
$q = "INSERT INTO rw_promo_code (id, rw_app_id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining) VALUES ('$increase', '$rw_app_id', '$email', '$unlock', '$numOf')";
```

else

```
$q = "INSERT INTO rw_promo_code ( rw_app_id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining) VALUES ( '$rw_app_id', '$email', '$unlock', '$numOf')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get last id with `order by id`

```
SELECT id FROM rw_promo_code ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **id** field is a auto increment field . So in this case you do not need the last insert id. your query should be

```
 $q = "INSERT INTO rw_promo_code ( rw_app_id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining) VALUES ('$rw_app_id', '$email', '$unlock', '$numOf')";
```